# apachectl in two locations causing difficulty

Tags: macos, mac, apache-http-server

I'm setting up a dev environment on a mac OS-X (10.8.3).

My `apachectl` seems to be referencing `/opt/usr/sbin/apachectl`:

```
$ sudo apachectl start
$ ps aux | grep httpd | grep -v grep
_www             898   0.0  0.0  2436168    704   ??  S    11:46AM   0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
root             897   0.0  0.1  2436168   4308   ??  Ss   11:46AM   0:00.18 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

However, `apachectl` in `/opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl` seems to be driving the (correctly configured) webserver for my local machine.

```
$ sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
$ ps aux | grep httpd | grep -v grep
_www             916   0.0  0.0  2455992    688   ??  S    11:47AM   0:00.00 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
_www             915   0.0  0.0  2455992    688   ??  S    11:47AM   0:00.00 /opt/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
```

I installed MAMP, before realizing I didn't want it and removing it. As far as I can tell `apachectl` is not aliased:

```
$ alias
alias ll='ls -la'
$
```

So I'm not sure, apart from deleting `apachectl` in `/usr/sbin/`, how to correct this - and that only with a new alias. That seems like a very unclean solution. Can anyone provide pointers on how to rewire my mac to no longer have this problem? Or even verify what `apachectl` is pointed to (or how to change that)? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does `whereis apachectl` give any output? That'll tell you where it's being pointed. If you have it in two locations most likely one of them is a symlink to the other. You can verify this with `ls -l` and it'll point out a symlink if there is one.

Comment: Ah! `whereis` was exactly what I needed to show where apachectl is. Thanks! It is definitely pointed to `/usr/sbin`... but what is doing that? It's not `alias`. Neither apachectl is a symlink.

Comment: Two separate apache installs maybe? Sometimes certain packages will install it as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `/usr/sbin/apachectl` is installed by default in OSX; and, probably not a good idea to delete it.  Instead, you could modify your `$PATH` environment variable so that `/opt/local/bin` takes precedence over `/usr/sbin`.  Beware that this can have unintended consequences if you have very many packages installed in `/opt/`, as some program versions might suddenly be different than what they were before.